# DLookUp doesn't return values for some users (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: permissions, spfieldlookupvalue

I have a Sharepoint 2010 library with 12 columns, we have a person that can only see the dropdown values for one of the 3 columns which are DLookUp type.
The one she does see is sourced from a list and she has permissions to the list.
Another one she does not see is also sourced from a different list, but she does have permission to the list (same as above).
And finally she does not see the values of a DLookup coming from a site content type.   This is not a problem for other staff.

I am unsure how to troubleshoot this.  What would affect a person's ability to see the dropdown values?    She views the list content from either a standard "new" form or "edit" form.  She can see the field on the form and tell there is a dropdown arrow - but it will not expand for her to see the values.

Your expert advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create another temporary lookup field in that list on one of those lookup lists and see if the same happens only to that user?